# COGNOS - Days Between Excluding Weekend

Tags: cognos

I Would Like To Count The Number Of Days Between Start Day [Start] and End Date [Finish];

My Current Code Works Fine, But Includes Weekends,

```
_days_between (IF ([Finish] is missing) THEN (current_date) ELSE (cast([Finish] as date)),cast([Start] as date)) + 1
```

Edit (Based On **Alexey Baturin** Answer):

```
1 + 5 * (_days_between (cast([Finish] as date);cast([Start] as date)) 
     -_day_of_week (cast([Finish] as date);1)+_day_of_week (cast([Start] as date);1))/7 
- if (_day_of_week (cast([Start] as date);1) > 5) then (6) else  (_day_of_week (cast([Start] as date);1)) 
+ if (_day_of_week (cast([Finish] as date);1) > 5) then (5) else (_day_of_week (cast([Finish] as date);1))
```

I Now Have This Code But This Doesn't Include If [Finish] Is Missing.

Comment: Do you have a materialized time dimension?

Comment: Sorry, I'm New To This So You'll Have To Expand, I Have SQL Table With Start and Finish Both 'Date' Type.

Comment: No, that's not what I mean. Cognos recommends to have a database table (e.g. `D_TIME`) with all relevant days in it. This table could be enhanced by a `IS_WEEKDAY` flag. Your problem would then boil down to counting the days with `IS_WEEKDAY=1`in that table between start date and end date.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
1 + (_week_of_year (IF ([Finish] is missing) THEN (current_date) ELSE (cast([Finish] as date))) - _week_of_year (cast([Start] as date))) * 5
- if (_day_of_week (cast([Start] as date),1) > 5) then (6) else  (_day_of_week (cast([Start] as date),1)) 
+ if (_day_of_week (IF ([Finish] is missing) THEN (current_date) ELSE (cast([Finish] as date)),1) > 5) then (5) else (_day_of_week (IF ([Finish] is missing) THEN (current_date) ELSE (cast([Finish] as date)),1))
```

Or simpler, to make the idea of calculation clear.

```
1 + (_week_of_year ([Finish]) - _week_of_year ([Start])) * 5
- if (_day_of_week ([Start];1) > 5) then (6) else  (_day_of_week ([Start];1)) 
+ if (_day_of_week ([Finish];1) > 5) then (5) else (_day_of_week ([Finish];1))
```

End of year bug fixed

```
1 + 5 * (_days_between ([Finish];[Start]) 
         -_day_of_week ([Finish];1)+_day_of_week ([Start];1))/7
- if (_day_of_week ([Start];1) > 5) then (6) else  (_day_of_week ([Start];1)) 
+ if (_day_of_week ([Finish];1) > 5) then (5) else (_day_of_week ([Finish];1))
```

Comment: And if the need to go through something like this (clever though it is) doesn't convince you to use a date table, nothing will.

Comment: No, Marcus. End of year is a problem for this formula

Comment: End of year bug fixed

Comment: Please See My Edit, Alexey.

Comment: Replace cast([Finish] as date) with IF ([Finish] is missing) THEN (current_date) ELSE (cast([Finish] as date))